# How to stop the elements from growing when hovering over an element?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I am trying to design the header for a project through which I am learning React with SASS. The header looks as follows:
[image]

Now when I am hovering over the "Sign In" button, the following problem is arising:
[image]

The problem might not be clear, but the when I am hovering over the Sign In button, all the other elements are shifting towards left for a few pixels. But, this transition is visible.

The SCSS code is as follows:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #8DBF44;

    .logo {
        height: 40px;
        width: 15%;
        // padding: 25px;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .options {
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        // padding-right: 20px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;

        .option {
            padding: 20px 30px;
            margin: 0 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            transition: 0.2s linear;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;

            &:hover {
                // cursor: pointer;
                // height: 80%;
                // padding: 10px 0;
                border-top: 2px solid #F9EA32;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #F9EA32;
                color: #F9EA32;
            }
        }

        #signIn {
            // padding-left: 40px;
            // padding-right: 40px;
            // padding-top: 12px;
            // padding-bottom: 12px;
            // box-sizing: content-box;
            padding: 12px 40px;
            background: #F9EA32;
            color:rgb(5, 78, 23);
            border-radius: 30px;
            border: none;
            display: inline-block;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;

            &:hover {
                border: 2px solid #F9EA32;
                // cursor: pointer;
                background: white;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the JSX code is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../../images/logo.png';
import './header.styles.scss';

const Header = () => (
    <div className='header'>
        <div className='logo'>
            <img src={logo} alt='Instant Pickup' />
        </div>
        <div className='options'>
            <a className='option'>About Us</a>
            <a className='option'>Become a Driver</a>
            <a className='option'>Blog</a>
            <a className='option'>Support</a>
            <a className='option' id='signIn'>
                Sign In
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default Header;
```

I believe the error is with my CSS logic. I have a tried adjusting the padding and margin, but the problem remains. I know it is a basic question, but I would appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is happening is because you add a border of 2px to the sign in button on hover and that adds a total of 4 pixels to the buttons height and width.

The solution is to have the border also on the not hover state just color it transparent so it isn't visible like this

```
#signIn {
    padding: 12px 40px;
    background: #F9EA32;
    color:rgb(5, 78, 23);
    border-radius: 30px;
    //** add this line
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;

    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid #F9EA32;
        background: white;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can color the border the same color as the button when not hovered like this

```
#signIn {
    padding: 12px 40px;
    background: #F9EA32;
    color:rgb(5, 78, 23);
    border-radius: 30px;
    //** add this line
    border: 2px solid #F9EA32;
    display: inline-block;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;

    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid #F9EA32;
        background: white;
    }
}
```

This will make it look like part of the button and only on hover it will change to the other border color.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution too, and it is also working well.

Comment: The benefit of this solution is that you don't have to limit yourself by setting an explicit height/width to your button which might be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution can be , you can put the sign in button inside a div, and give div a specific width . EG: 150px

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../../images/logo.png';
import './header.styles.scss';

const Header = () => (
    <div className='header'>
        <div className='logo'>
            <img src={logo} alt='Instant Pickup' />
        </div>
        <div className='options'>
            <a className='option'>About Us</a>
            <a className='option'>Become a Driver</a>
            <a className='option'>Blog</a>
            <a className='option'>Support</a>
           <div className='signup-container'>
              <a className='option' id='signIn'>
                  Sign In
              </a>
           <div>

        </div>
    </div>
);

export default Header;
```

the signup container can be

```
.signup-container {
widht: 150px;
background-color: transparent
}
```

Comment: This works for other elements. But now the sign-in button moves to the right by few pixels.

Comment: 150 px is just an assumption, you can give it the proper width as you see fit, to center the element you can add {dispaly: flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center} inside .signup-container

Comment: Yes, I used the dev tools to find the correct width. I will try other things as well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Actually, making the button the same size as that of the signup-container worked. So I set both of them to same width.